# NEISS injury dataset - machine readable coding for characterizations

Tags: medical, metadata

The [National Electronic Injury Surveillance System (NEISS)](http://www.cpsc.gov/en/Research--Statistics/NEISS-Injury-Data/) database offers Excel downloads (example [XLSX](http://www.cpsc.gov/Global/Neiss_prod/NEISS-data-2015-updated-APRIL2016.xlsx), ~50MB) on a year by year basis. The categorization of the injuries in the Excel files is given by codes, which may change or merge year to year. The codes are available in the Coding Manual [PDF](http://www.cpsc.gov//Global/Neiss_prod/2016NonTraumaNEISSCodingManual.pdf), and changes are available in the 2016 Comparability Table [PDF](http://www.cpsc.gov//Global/Neiss_prod/2016ComparabilityTable.pdf).

The [query tool](http://www.cpsc.gov/cgibin/NEISSQuery/home.aspx) hides the codes from the user and shows only the characterizations (e.g. Diagnosis).

**Is there a machine readable source for the mapping between codes and descriptions?**

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: how does one get to this data? clicking query throws a 404

Comment: ah, nm, went to main page, see the list. my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the PDF manual, there is an R package on Github called **[Neiss](https://github.com/hadley/neiss)** that has an excel file with mapping between codes and text descriptions.

Direct link: https://github.com/hadley/neiss/blob/master/data-raw/NEISS-formats.xlsx

Sample screenshot:

[image]

In addition to diagnosis there is also product code, race codes, etc.