# NEISS injury dataset - machine readable and decoded

Tags: data-request, releasing-data, medical

The [National Electronic Injury Surveillance System](http://www.cpsc.gov/en/Research--Statistics/NEISS-Injury-Data/) (NEISS) database offers both a [query tool](https://www.cpsc.gov/cgibin/NEISSQuery/home.aspx) and bulk CSV downloads at maximum one calendar year. The available data dates back to 1991.

> Patient information is collected from each NEISS hospital for every emergency visit involving an injury associated with consumer products. From this sample, the total number of product-related injuries treated in hospital emergency rooms nationwide can be estimated.
>
> Records are weighted to estimate the total population.

Here's a fun [twitter-bot](https://twitter.com/usinjuries) using this data:

[image]

---

---

There are two issues: (1) files are individually downloaded by year, and (2) CSV files contain encoding, for which the metadata is in PDF files and websites (see [my other question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/9150/1511) related to this)

My question: **Where can I find multi-year datasets that are decoded?** (contain actualy injury and cause, and not just an ID number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have manually downloaded the individual files and combined them into several file formats.

- Gist: [Python script](https://gist.github.com/philshem/3015de98de26df1681635244c95186aa) and [product_code](https://gist.github.com/philshem/3015de98de26df1681635244c95186aa#file-product_codes-tsv) mapping

**Combined files**, total rows = 8,852,972

- [data.world repository](https://data.world/philshem/neiss-injury-dataset-unofficial-export)
- [CSV sample](https://query.data.world/s/985weus44plcdhjf8dqd24yed)
- [Full export - zip:CSV](https://query.data.world/s/9pa5hnowk989rmml3m6i5zk5t) (440 MB compressed, 3.2 GB unpacked)
- [Full export zip:sqlite3](https://query.data.world/s/5nq04umnosmifl33kc63gywsr) (717 MB compressed, 4.0 GB unpacked)

---

Related

- [Data visualization with 2015 data](http://flowingdata.com/2016/02/09/why-people-visit-the-emergency-room/)
- [R Package "Neiss"](https://github.com/hadley/neiss) from Hadley Wickham
- [Python consolidation project](https://github.com/avmotamed/neiss)